# Intersection of n Strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am working on a program to find the characters of the intersection of n strings.I write the following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestJoin {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


      int n=sc.nextInt();  // no of strings
      String s1 =sc.next().toLowerCase();
      ArrayList<Character> set1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
      while(n-->1)
      {
          String s2 =sc.next().toLowerCase();
          ArrayList<Character> set2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
          for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
                set1.add(c);
            }
          for(char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
                set2.add(c);
            }
          set1.retainAll(set2);
          for(char c : set1)
          {
              s1=Character.toString(c);
          }
      }
       for(char c :set1)
      System.out.println(c);


  }
}
```

When I try to print the character it gives wrong output.

Input-

```
 3
 aabcde
 abazx
 yuabna
```

Expected output: **aab**

Actual Output:**aabb**

Comment: You didn't ask a question!

Comment: What do you mean by "intersection"? How do you get `aab` from the given input? Why not `aba` or `baa`?

Comment: Also please post a **complete** code example which compiles without any errors.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Order does not matter (aab,aba,baa) all are same.Intersection means common characters among all strings

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and **describe in words** the steps required to solve the problem. This will help you figure out how to modify your code to follow those steps. Then if you still have the wrong output, you can use some debugging skills to find the problems. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug y our code.

Comment: How big `n` can be?

Comment: @Ken Bekov   Maximum value of n is 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a separate method often makes problems smaller and easier to solve.

I suggest you first make a method to calculate the intersection of 2 `String`, and then you can use it in your `while` loop to calculate the intersection of the incoming strings with the current intersection.

I tried to keep your logic, and I wrote my own retain loop as I am not sure of what the `List.retainAll` does

This method calculates the intersection of 2 `String`:

```
private static String intersectionOf(String s1, String s2) {
    List<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
        list1.add(c);
    }
    List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
        list2.add(c);
    }

    StringBuilder intersection = new StringBuilder();
    for(Character c : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(c)) {
            intersection.append(c);
            list2.remove(c); // remove it so it is not counted twice
        }
    }
    return intersection.toString();
}
```

You can now use it in your loop, the logic looks lot simpler

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = sc.nextInt();  // no of strings

    String result = sc.next().toLowerCase();
    String s;
    while(n-- > 1) {
        s = sc.next().toLowerCase();
        result = intersectionOf(result, s);
    }
    for(char c : result.toCharArray())
        System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: This approach has the added benefit of speed if your strings are long and numerous, but the intersection is relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void intersect(String... input) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> mins = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> current = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (String s : input) {
        current.clear();
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        //Next loop remembers how many time every char occurs
        for (char c : chars) {
            Integer value = current.get(c);
            if (value == null) value = 0;
            current.put(c, value + 1);
        }

        if (mins.size() == 0) {
            mins.putAll(current); //First time just copy
        } else {
           //If not the first time then compare with previous results
            for (Character c : mins.keySet()) {
                Integer min = mins.get(c);
                Integer cur = current.get(c);
                if (cur != null) {
                    if (min > cur) {
                        //If has less than all previous
                        mins.put(c, cur);
                    }
                } else {
                    //If doesn't have at all
                    mins.put(c, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Output every char that occurs in every string
    //more that 0 times
    for (Character c : mins.keySet()) {
        Integer count = mins.get(c);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And invocation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   intersect("aabcdeabazx", "abazx", "yuabna");
}
```

You can change arguments to pass them as array. The calculation complexity of this algorythm is approximately O(n).

Comment: This is definitely not O(n) as you are using nested loops here. Also might he helpful not to change too much of the OP's code.

Comment: @NicholasK saying O always means the complexity growth function. With increasing of input data the growth function of this algorithm is linear (at least very close to linear). Therefore complexity is O(n).

Comment: @NicholasK second loop won't grow more than 26 (for small letters of English alphabet), no matter how many strings we have in input.